# Is there a way to tuneup a complex count query against heavy data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008

There are two tables one is **empl** having **545405** records and second is **pam** having **1466320** records. The task is to find the count of **pID** according **aID**. So to acomplish this task I write the following query.

```
Select pa.aID, count(pa.pID) from 
empl join pam pa
ON empl.pID = pa.pID
Group by pa.aID
```

The indexes for **pam** are as following:

```
IX_pam_Unique   nonclustered, unique, unique key located on PRIMARY     pID, aID
IX_pam_aID      nonclustered located on PRIMARY                         aID
PK_paID         clustered, unique, primary key located on PRIMARY       paID
```

The Actual Execution plan shows Index Scan:

[image] 
[image]

What I can understand is that there is Estimated Data Size of **15 MB** which is causing the problem.

Is there a way to tuneup this complex count query against heavy data?

**Edit:**

The query with empl filters:

```
Select pa.aID, count(pa.pID) from 
empl join pam pa
ON empl.pID = pa.pID
where 
empl.del = 0 AND 
empl.pub = 1 AND 
empl.sID = 2 AND 
empl.md = 0          
Group by pa.aID
```

And there is nothing fancy in the structures, only basic datatypes int, bit, varchar and datatime is used. There are **65** columns in **empl** and **4** columns in **pam**

Comment: Why you need to join on empl table? 
`Select pa.aID, count(pa.pID) from pam pa Group by pa.aID`

Comment: @AnupAgrawal: Actually I have to do some basic filters over the empl and will decrease the data by only 1%. That's why I haven't mention the filter in the question and alter the query according main object.

Comment: Please post your exact query. "Some basic filters" that "decrease the data by only 1%" are likely to have huge impact on execution plan and performance. Also table structure and column types could be helpful.

Comment: @NenadZivkovic: Query Posted with structure details, please check edit.

Comment: what indexes are there on empl? the slowdown is likely scanning through the empl table, not doing the count. 65 columns is a lot for a long table

Comment: @ChrisBednarski: One clustered index on "pID" and one composite index on all used columns (del, pub, sID, md, pID).

Comment: @i-one: Yes, I had rebuild indexes and updated statistics of both tables.

Comment: Which nonclustered index is being scanned?

Comment: @ChrisBednarski: IX_pam_Unique

Comment: have you tried an index in the reverse order? aID, pID?

Comment: Yes, I tried but optimizer is ignoring it, so I tried index hint but still it's going for a scan.

Answer (score 1):

Possible this be helpful for you -

```
SELECT pa.*
FROM empl
JOIN (
    SELECT 
          pa.aID
        , cnt = COUNT(pa.pid)
    FROM pam pa 
    GROUP BY pa.aID
) pa ON empl.pid = pa.pid
```

Or this -

```
SELECT pa.aID, COUNT(pa.pid)
FROM pam pa
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM empl 
    WHERE empl.pid = pa.pid
)
GROUP BY pa.aID
```

Or even this -

```
SELECT 
      pa.aID
    , cnt = COUNT(pa.pid)
FROM pam pa 
GROUP BY pa.aID
```

Comment: Please make me right if I misunderstood, when I executed the first query I got error "Invalid column name 'pid'." And there is no difference in Estimated Data size with your second query.

Comment: Sorry, but syntax in first query is good. Why you think that `Estimated Data Size` decrease your performance? Can you show your query plan?

Comment: I found difference in duration 1302ms(my query), 1077ms(your second query). But it's not up to the goal.

Answer (score 1):

Keep the query as it is, add an index on `empl` which includes only del, pub, sid, md and pid columns. Make sure pid is the last column in the index.

Edit:
Alternative query to try could be

```
SELECT DISTINCT pa.aID, COUNT(pa.pID) OVER (PARTITION BY pa.aID) AS cnt
FROM empl JOIN pam pa
ON empl.pID = pa.pID
WHERE
empl.del = 0 AND 
empl.pub = 1 AND 
empl.sID = 2 AND 
empl.md = 0
```

Notice how this one doesn't need the `GROUP BY`. Not sure how faster/slower it will be. The query plan will be different to the one with `GROUP BY` though.

EDIT:
You're right. I've added `DISTINCT`

Comment: @ChrisBednarski: I had never used COUNT() OVER (PARTITION BY, but when I execute your query, I got this error: "The COUNT function requires 1 argument(s)." Then I put the pID column inside Count but the result is all wrong. Please make me right if I'm wrong somewhere.

Comment: @Prakash Are the filters on `empl` table static? If so, try a filtered index.

Comment: Yes, they are static but 99% data comes under this condition.

Answer (score 0):

For static conditions you may try indexed view:

```
create view vPamCnt
with schemabinding
as
Select pa.aID, count_big(*) cnt
from dbo.pam pa
    join dbo.empl empl ON empl.pID = pa.pID
where 
    empl.del = 0 AND
    empl.pub = 1 AND
    empl.sID = 2 AND
    empl.md = 0
Group by pa.aID
GO
create unique clustered index CI_vPamCnt on vPamCnt (aID)
GO
```

and change your query to just:

```
select aID, cast(cnt as int)
from vPamCnt
```